# How to test without declaring class public Java, to preserve encapsulation

Tags: java, testing, junit, encapsulation

In Swift, it is possible to test an package private class by using `@testable` annotation in the test class. I was just wondering if there is anyway to test a package private class in Java without declaring it public?

Comment: If you place the "test" class in same package(different source tree), it has necessary access. Does that help?

Comment: I thought by default, test classes are placed into the same project, but into their own package, right? if I have to place test class into the same package, does that mean both normal class and test class are mixed together?

Comment: They go into different directories. Source folders and 'test folders'.  The test typically have different compile and runtime requirements. Typically build tools provide an easy way to manage this (see gradle for example)